# vb.net selected radio button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have the following radion button in VB.NET

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbedit" runat="server"  RepeatDirection="horizontal" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" >Yes</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" >No</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:RadioButtonList></td>
```

I need to figure what button the user clicked on and then set a variable with that value.
How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rbedit.SelectedIndex to get which button user clicked and then set the variable accordingly.

If you want to get it client side then use following code :

```
function getRadVal(radlist)
{
 if (document.forms['Form1'].elements[radlist])
 {  var radGrp = document.forms['Form1'].elements[radlist];
  var radGrpValue = '0';
  for (var i = 0; i < radGrp.length; i++) 
      if (radGrp[i].checked) {
          radGrpValue = radGrp[i].value;
                break;
      } 
  return radGrpValue;
 }
 else
  return '';
}
```

to call this use :
// Get Value of RadioButtonList

var myValue=getRadVal('rbedit');

Answer (score 0):

Use `rbedit.selectedvalue` inside a button event handler.